# An expression of non-boolean type

Tags: sql

With this:

```
select puser_id, puser_name, plast_login_time, plicense_level =
    case 
        when '1' then 'Потребитель'
        else 'Автор'
    end 
from dbo.PPOM_USER
order by plast_login_time
```

I have error like this:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'then'.

Please help me to find the problem in code.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Just in case...)

Comment: `plicense_level = case ... end` is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers

Answer (score 1):

Change your `WHEN` to:

```
when plicense_level = '1'
```

You need to have a valid comparison in `WHEN` to avoid the error.

---

From the [**`CASE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) documentation:

> WHEN when_expression
>
> Is a simple expression to which input_expression is compared when the
> simple CASE format is used. when_expression is any valid expression.

Comment: If I do this:
`select puser_id, puser_name, plast_login_time, plicense_level =
 case plicense_level
  when plicense_level='1' then 'Потребитель'
  else 'Автор'
 end 
from dbo.PPOM_USER
order by plast_login_time`

I have this:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the CASE <strike>statement</strike> expression isn't quite right, try:

```
case plicense_level
    when '1' then 'Потребитель'
    else 'Автор'
end
```

Comment: Yes, I found this error too, but still have this:
The following items have errors: 

ReportDesign (id = 1): 
 + Unhandled exception when executing script. 


Table (id = 27383): 
 + A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Can not convert the value of Автор to Integer type.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.

Comment: Why it wants to convert '' to Integer type? I can't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying is to show the user a text describing the licennse instead of the numeric value of the column you should try something like this:

```
select 
    puser_id, 
    puser_name, 
    plast_login_time, 
    case plicense_level
        when '1' then 'Потребитель'
        else 'Автор'
    end as plicense_level
from dbo.PPOM_USER
order by plast_login_time
```

You can find some samples of CASE in [this page at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181765(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you!

The dicision was in changing data type of field plicense_level in report
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFo8s.png)

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luyg8.png)

Answer (score -2):

```
select puser_id, puser_name, plast_login_time, plicense_level =
case 
    when plicense_level = '1' then 'Потребитель'
    else 'Автор'
end 
from dbo.PPOM_USER
order by plast_login_time
```